# how to edit php.ini in CLI

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, terminal, command-line-interface

I am working on a symfony project using MAMP.

I am trying to load data into sql from Terminal with this script:

```
php symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

I am getting this error:

> *Couldn't locate driver named mysql*

The forums have explained you should have `pdo_sql` enabled.

This is enabled in `MAMP/conf/php5.2/php.ini` and `MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini`

The researched documentation states that the `php.ini` file in the CLI is different from the `php.ini` file located in apache.

How can I locate and edit the `php.ini` file in the CLI, which is obviously different from the ones located in the MAMP directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run this on the command line:

```
php -info | grep Confi
```

it should give you an output like

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

But you don't have to edit it. You can just simply use the one that is used by MAMP:

```
php -c /path/to/your/php.ini symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

Comment: When I run the first set of code, the is the return: 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

The Second set brings up another issue:
When I run php -c /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini symfony doctrine:insert-sql

I am still getting the error:
doctrine  creating tables
                                  
  Couldn't locate driver named mysql  
                                      
Any other ideas?

Comment: you just have to run `php -info | grep Confi`. The rest is output ;-)

Comment: Ah yes. The readout is:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /private/etc/php.ini

So I opened the php.ini file in that directory and found where the pdo_sql extension was deactivated (;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll &
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll)

When I activated the lines, I got this:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo_pgsql.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo_mysql.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0

Do I need to install or activate something else?

Comment: check, what your `extension_dir` is: `php -info | grep extension_dir` and see, if `pdo_mysql.so` is there.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have made multiple changes to multiple files. I'm not sure where it started working, but it is good to go now. I am going to go through my edits and hopefully it will help others with this issue.

First, I made files visible in the Finder using this script in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

Second, I located where my CLI php.ini file was located using Terminal(Thanks to Cassy) using the script he provided:

```
php -info | grep Confi
```

This outputs similar to:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /private/etc/php.ini
```

This location is **not** correct to activate the pdo_mysql.so file needed for symfony using MAMP.

So, in hammer to housefly fashion, I covered these steps:

1. Open php.ini in /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/ and copy the following line:

   extension=pdo_mysql.so
2. Open the php.ini in /private/etc/ (This is where you have to have hidden files set to visible), and paste the above code (extension=pdo_mysql.so) into the file. I pasted it under the commented out extensions, but I do not think it matters.
3. Open .bash_profile in the Users directory (This is normally your computer name, ie Carey, Steve, Holly)
4. Insert the following code:

   export PATH=:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin
5. Lastly, open httpd.conf and paste the following code:

   php_value include_path "/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini"
   PHPIniDir "/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini"

After restarting Apache, I looked at my php info in Terminal:

```
php -i
```

And it said this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini
```

Now in Terminal, type php -m and it will give you a list of php modules. Look for pdo_mysql in the list.

If it is there, using symfony to build and populate your database should work.